# Kombu in beans -- granules or powder OK?

Tags: beans

I have been using kombu in my beans for a couple of years and I love it: the beans are more tender and easier to digest, and the pot liquor is richer. I've noticed that there are kelp granules and powder for sale in a lot of health food stores. Two questions:

1. Do all varieties of kelp help beans the way that kombu does in
   particular?
2. Can kelp granules or powder be used in place of whole kombu when cooking beans?

Thanks!

Comment: Curious, I've never heard of using kombu. I usually use a small amount of hing/asafoetida to reduce discomfort and baking soda to soften.

Comment: Interesting about hing -- I'll have to investigate! According to Miss Vickie, baking soda degrades vitamin content, though she doesn't cite her sources: http://missvickie.com/howto/beans/bakingsoda.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that there are studies on using different kinds of kelp with beans, but I have used both kombu strips and kelp granules interchangeably when cooking beans. The results seem to be the same either way.